# GeoWebCache tiles hiding vector layers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache

I'm using **OpenLayers 2.13, GeoServer 2.3.5** for development.

I have a **GeoWebCache layer** as base layer and one vector layer for showing route (please check the attached image).

If I drag or zoom in to any part of that route layer map tile is hiding rest of the vector layer part.

Please guide me to show all my vector layer in all zoom level.

[image]

Comment: what is providing the vector layer? could it be that it isn't redrawing?

Comment: Dear iant, thank you for your response... my vector layer having polyline features. all the data i'm fetching from database and i got the result like i have showed in image 1. But, after that if i do any drag or zoom in map then map tiles are hiding my results. That is my problem..

Comment: did you redraw the vector layer?

Comment: Dear iant, Yes.. I have missed that option. :) Thank you for the answer.. map.getLayersByName(vectorlayerName)[0].redraw(); Please post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading all the datas in vector layer we have to redraw vector layer.
**map.getLayersByName(vectorlayerName)[0].redraw();**

Thank you @iant. :)